# How to instruct FullSimplify to assume that PossibleZeroQ returns correct result?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Sometimes I have a really huge expression that cannot be significantly simplified by `FullSimplify`. I would like to, so to speak, *"simplify with faith"* using heuristics applied by functions like `PossibleZeroQ`, `FindSequenceFunction` an so on. Is it possible to instruct `FullSimplify` to use non-rigorous methods like this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sometimes I use the following:

```
FullSimplify[
  1 + Sqrt[2] Log[2] - Sqrt[3] Log[3] - Sqrt[5] Log[5] + 
  Sqrt[2 (9 + 4 Sqrt[2]) Log[2]^2 + 3 Log[3]^2 - 2 Log[2] (Sqrt[3] (4 + Sqrt[2]) Log[3] +
  4 Sqrt[5] Log[5]) + Log[5] (-Sqrt[10] Log[4] + 5 Log[5] + Sqrt[15] Log[9])] + Log[16], 
    TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, 
      If[Not[AtomQ[#]] && NumericQ[#] && PossibleZeroQ[# - Round[#]], Round[#], #] &}]
```

It helps to get a conjectured simple representation of an expression, which then I can try to prove rigorously.